# How to display messages in jsp according to class errors

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jsp-tags

here's my Form Class:

```
public ArrayList<ForbesData> loadData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception   {
    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
     .....
    try {
  ......
 }
catch (NullPointerException e) {
        errors.add("fich", new ActionMessage("error.file.required"));
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        errors.add("crap", new ActionMessage("error.crapull.required"));
    }
    catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        errors.add("exc", new ActionMessage("error.excell.required"));
    }
```

Here's my ApplicationResource.properties:

```
error.fich.required= folder doesn't exist!
error.crapull.required=folder isn't crapull!
error.excell.required=folder isn't excel!
```

here's my struts-config:

```
      <struts-config>
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="UserForm" type="net.cacib.struts.UserForm" /> 
</form-beans>



<action-mappings>
    <action input="/" name="UserForm" path="/userAction" scope="session" validate="true"
        type="net.cacib.struts.UserAction">
        <forward name="success" path="/index.jsp" />
    </action>



    <action path="/Welcome" forward="/welcomeStruts.jsp" />
</action-mappings>

<message-resources parameter="/WEB-INF/ApplicationResource" />
```

in my jsp:

```
 <html:errors property="crap" />
 <html:errors property="fich" />
 <html:errors property="exc" />
```

what I want to do is display error messages to the user each time an exception is thrown.

Do you have any idea what I need to change my code to achieve this goal. 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

And what happens now? If it's that you only show one error, it's because *you* are throwing an exception and have only a *single* catch block.

If you want to catch all of them and *accumulate* errors then you need to put a try/catch around each *individual* chunk of code that can throw the exceptions.

Comment: what i want to do is  to display an error  message to the user depending of the exception thrown

Comment: @user3333294 And what happens now? In order to answer a question we need to know what's actually wrong.

Comment: what's wrong is that I can not display error messages in jsp page

Comment: by posting here I just wante to know if it's logical what i was doing

Comment: @user3333294 If you only want to capture one error, sure, it's probably pretty close.

Comment: and what should i modify to catch all errors and to display at least one error in jsp page

Comment: @user3333294 Do precisely what I told you to do: wrap each chunk in its own try/catch block.

Comment: Stop using Struts, start using Struts2. Then do this kind of validation in XML, or with Annotations, or in `validate()` method by programmatically adding all the fieldErrors you need

Comment: @user3333294 "Doesn't work" isn't helpful; we need more information.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Not always practical ;)

Comment: this is why I wonder if my logic is good or not. 

I'm looking on the net but I find no case that looks like my problem

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, porting is not always possible / convenient, but... Struts1 in 2014 ? It's sick. [Slide 26](http://www.slideshare.net/mraible/comparing-jvm-web-frameworks-february-2014) explains it well :D

Comment: @user3333294 Are you saving the errors? How are the errors related to the actual action method, which this isn't?

Comment: @AndreaLigios The worst part is that I know companies that are doing *new* apps in Struts 1. It doesn't make *any* sort of sense.

Comment: @DaveNewton [Normalcy bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalcy_bias) at company level...

Comment: @AndreaLigios WE MUST CLING TO THE PAST TO REACH THE FUTURE

Comment: do you think it is obvious to migrate an application to struts2 from struts1?

sorry for my bad english i'm french ^^

Comment: @user3333294 Your english is fine :) If it's worth the cost to migrate depends on a lot of factors, so I wouldn't guess without knowing more.